# how to pas value object into parameter function?

Tags: javascript, api

I have some problem when i tried to passing some value from API, using onclick

here is my API

```js
let alldata = [
  {
    days: 1,
    days_name: "Monday",
    month_name: "February",
    year: "2021",
    program: [
      {
        title: "DragonBall",
        cam: {
          length: 3,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        lig: {
          length: 1,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        aud: {
          length: 0,
          crew: [],
        },
        crp: {
          length: 3,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        tp: {
          length: 1,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        title: "DragonBall",
        cam: {
          length: 3,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119090",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119012",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        lig: {
          length: 1,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        aud: {
          length: 0,
          crew: [],
        },
        crp: {
          length: 3,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
        tp: {
          length: 1,
          crew: [
            {
              nik: "119092",
              nama: "Rizwan",
              department: "Production Services",
              occupation: "camera",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];


// get data class and id
let months = document.getElementById("monthly");
let htitle = document.getElementById("htitle");
let month = document.getElementById("bulan");
let table = "";
let result = "";
let fortitle = "";
let allvalue = alldata.length;

month.innerHTML = `${alldata[0].month_name}`;

htitle.innerHTML = `${alldata[0].days} - ${alldata[allvalue - 1].days} ${
  alldata[0].month_name
}`;

// showing into div

alldata.map((element, index) => {
  table = `<table border="1">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="6">${element.days_name} ${element.days} ${element.month_name} ${element.year}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width:100px">Program</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px">Cam</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px">Lig</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px">Aud</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px">CRP</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px">TP</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody class="program">`;

  let everyprog = "";

  element.program.map((value, index) => {
    
    everyprog += `<tr>
                      <td>${value.title}</td>
                      <td class="cameraperson""><span onclick="helo(${value.cam.crew})" style="cursor: pointer;">${value.cam.length}</span></td>
                      <td>${value.lig.length}</td>
                      <td>${value.aud.length}</td>
                      <td>${value.crp.length}</td>
                      <td>${value.tp.length}</td>
                  `;
  });

  let ending = ` </tr></tbody>
                </table>`;

  result += table + everyprog + ending;
});

months.innerHTML = result;

function helo(vallue) {
  
   alert(vallue);
}

//let campers = document.querySelectorAll(".cameraperson");

//campers.onclick();
// console.log(campers.length);
```

```css
body {
  display: inline;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 17%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  /* float: right; */
}

#monthly {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  /* padding: 0 10% 0 10%; */
  /* background-color: aquamarine; */
}

#navigasi {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navigasi">Nav</div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="weekstitle">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Monthly <span id="bulan"></span></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="weeksheader">
        <h2 id="htitle" style="text-align: center"></h2>
      </div>
      <div id="monthly"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to send those crew into my function and get that value from onlick that will be send into my functions, so i can do something out of it but every time i click the number i get error unexpected identifier. I hope i don't have to use jquery and do something like get elementbyid or else, because there is to much data to search, so i hope i just can pass it like that

Comment: Use `Ctrl+M` to create snippet. You should share full working or not working code. The code must include HTML, CSS and JS. This will make it much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: woaw this snippet is very helpfull, but my problem still unresolved